# Need to make WordPress Form Submission trigger a process that registers New User on other Site

Tags: php, wordpress, selenium

My problem is:

I have a WordPress website and I want it to work so that every time somebody registers him/herself as a New User on my WordPress site, it triggers a process which takes their login credentials from my WordPress site and uses them to create a new user on a second site, using those same credentials. The second site is a process management tool and is password protected. So this process / script would have to log in to the second site using my login credentials, navigate to the new sub-user registration form  and paste in the credentials and submit the form.

I have tried a couple different methods for this already, so far unsuccessful and am unsure what to do next. The second site is called Pruvan. I have checked with them and their API does not support new sub-user registration. I have also tried writing a script that would sit on the Front-End of the WordPress site, gather the new user's login credentials from the DOM, and then make an HTTP Post request to Pruvan's server API. This also did not work. I'm not sure exactly the reason why, but I think it is because Pruvan does not support Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.

I'm trying to find a solution for this problem. Right now I have a vague idea of using a testing framework (such as Selenium) to make a virtual user go to the Pruvan website, log in, and create the sub-user using the login credentials collected from the DOM. The issue I'm having here is that I have no idea how to start making this work with the WordPress Back-End. I have very little experience working with WordPress or PHP and would greatly appreciate some suggestions or a roadmap / blueprint of how you would approach this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: double check with them. they should provide APIs for creating new users. if not, that's some dumb pms you're working with

Comment: I agree. I emailed their support desk and they said their API doesn't support User Registration; that other people have gotten around this by using virtual users and webscraping.

Comment: Hi, if you found out the solution, make sure to post it down in the answer section. that would help others, plus that'd be interesting. anyways, I was thinking of may be scrapping to get the job done. PHP alone would suffice. by getting the `form action` and make `curl request as POST` on it with all fields data. just a suggestion..

Comment: this is the course I've decided to take, from asking around elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also believe that doing this using Selenium would not be right thing.

However, if you have not found a good solution and looking at this approach as a stop gap arrangement, here is how you can do this using Selenium:

- You may write a simple cron job that monitors your WordPress database for user registration
- If the cron detects a new user registration, it triggers your selenium script.

You may create a jar file or similar executable for the selenium script which can be triggered as a job with username and password as parameters. For example, if you have created a jar titled `InputInPMS.jar`, then you may trigger the jar using command:

`InputInPMS.jar <username> <password>`

Alternatively, you may use a build tool like jenkins to trigger a custom job through job link and passing username and password as parameters in the link to trigger job.

Comment: amazing response, thank you. Any reason this couldn't work in perpetuity?

Comment: This is because every time your pms does a UI update(including minor DOM changes), it is quite likely going to impact your selenium script and you will be required to refactor your locators/script. Also, this approach would be hard to scale once your sign ups increase

Comment: doing it trhough Selenium would not be the right thing; so what would you do instead?

Comment: I would probably look at something like google chrome puppeteer to do this. It also has the overhead of maintaining a script but it can be scaled easily.